# how do I bind a bot to a specific chat on discord

Tags: chat, bots, discord

I have a couple of bots running on the same server and they are responding to the same messages. I want to bind each bot to different chat channel so they would only respond to the messages meant for certain bots.

Comment: Quick google search: You could try changing the bots read/write permissions ( [apart from in the default channel](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/4nfwi0/activate_bots_only_through_a_specific_text_channel/) )

Comment: Found another way by adding a command in the options.ini but thanks for the idea

Comment: Nice! You might want to write that as an answer here then

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.on("message", message => {
    if (message.channel.id != config.singleChannelID) return;
    //do stuff
});
```

This will make the bot only listen to one channel.

However, what you really want to be doing is changing the command prefix for one for the bots. 
Example:

`bot1: ?help

bot2: !help`